# PHP including files it shouldnt because of an if condition

Tags: php, if-statement

Hi I have a crazy probem.

I try to Include different files depending on conditions. The code is the following of the experiment.php:

```
    <?php session_start();
/*

MO = Menu-Order

TD = Top-Down-Menu
SP = Side-Pull-Menu
R  = Radial-Menu

   | Reihenfolge  || Aufgabennummer     |
---+--------------++--------------------+-
MO | TD | SP |  R || T TD | T SP |  T R |
---+----+----+----++------+------+------+-
 1 |  1 |  2 |  3 ||    1 |    2 |    3 |
 2 |  1 |  3 |  2 ||    2 |    3 |    1 |
 3 |  2 |  1 |  3 ||    3 |    1 |    2 |
 4 |  2 |  3 |  1 ||    1 |    3 |    2 |
 5 |  3 |  1 |  2 ||    2 |    1 |    3 |
 6 |  3 |  2 |  1 ||    3 |    2 |    1 |


Aufgabennummer:

Task1: Top-News -> Wirtschaft -> Reise      -> Wissen     -> Wirtschaft
Task2: Top-News -> Wissen     -> Sport      -> Netzwelt   -> Wissen
Task3: Top-News -> Kultur     -> Top-News   -> Reise      -> Kultur

*/

    //echo '<pre>'; print_r($_SESSION); echo '</pre>';

    $task_1 = array(
        0 => array(
            'category' => 'Wirtschaft',
            'article'  => 'Faule Kredite steigen auf Rekordniveau',
            'done'     => 0,
            'clicks'   => 0,
            'start_time' => 0,
            'end_time'   => 0
        ), 
        1 => array(
            'category' => 'Reise',
            'article'  => 'Die Haxen des Bösen',
            'done'     => 0,
            'clicks'   => 0,
            'start_time' => 0,
            'end_time'   => 0
        ), 
        2 => array(
            'category' => 'Wissen',
            'article'  => 'Kulante Eltern haben kulante Kinder',
            'done'     => 0,
            'clicks'   => 0,
            'start_time' => 0,
            'end_time'   => 0
        ), 
        3 => array(
            'category' => 'Wirtschaft',
            'article'  => 'Schweiz stoppt Skilift-Lieferung an Kim Jong Un',
            'done'     => 0,
            'clicks'   => 0,
            'start_time' => 0,
            'end_time'   => 0
        )
    );


    $task_2 = array(
        0 => array(
            'category' => 'Wissen',
            'article'  => 'Delfinsterben bleibt Rätselhaft',
            'done'     => 0,
            'clicks'   => 0,
            'start_time' => 0,
            'end_time'   => 0
        ), 
        1 => array(
            'category' => 'Sport',
            'article'  => 'Almaty bewirbt sich um Winterspiele 2022',
            'done'     => 0,
            'clicks'   => 0,
            'start_time' => 0,
            'end_time'   => 0
        ), 
        2 => array(
            'category' => 'Netzwelt',
            'article'  => 'Samsung kürt geklautes Bild zum Siegerfoto',
            'done'     => 0,
            'clicks'   => 0,
            'start_time' => 0,
            'end_time'   => 0
        ), 
        3 => array(
            'category' => 'Wissen',
            'article'  => 'Kulante Eltern haben kulante Kinder',
            'done'     => 0,
            'clicks'   => 0,
            'start_time' => 0,
            'end_time'   => 0
        )
    );

    $task_3 = array(
        0 => array(
            'category' => 'Kultur',
            'article'  => 'Spanische Rentnerin soll an Einnahmen beteiligt werden',
            'done'     => 0,
            'clicks'   => 0,
            'start_time' => 0,
            'end_time'   => 0
        ), 
        1 => array(
            'category' => 'Top-News',
            'article'  => 'Unfallserie blockiert Rhein in Köln',
            'done'     => 0,
            'clicks'   => 0,
            'start_time' => 0,
            'end_time'   => 0
        ), 
        2 => array(
            'category' => 'Reise',
            'article'  => 'Verkehrschaos in der Lagune',
            'done'     => 0,
            'clicks'   => 0,
            'start_time' => 0,
            'end_time'   => 0
        ), 
        3 => array(
            'category' => 'Kultur',
            'article'  => 'Schlaflos mit Schlingel',
            'done'     => 0,
            'clicks'   => 0,
            'start_time' => 0,
            'end_time'   => 0
        )
    );

    $sp = 'index-sidepull.php';
    $r  = 'index-radial.php';
    $td = 'index-topdown.php';


    $menu_order = 1;

    // Fortschritts Variablen setzen wenn nicht gesetzt

    if(!isset($_SESSION['progress']) or !isset($_SESSION['initial'])){
        $_SESSION['progress'] = 0;
        $_SESSION['initial']  = 1;
    }

    // Fortschritt initialisieren wenn nicht vorhanden

    if($_SESSION['progress'] == 0){

        $_SESSION['menu'][1]['done'] = 0;
        $_SESSION['menu'][2]['done'] = 0;
        $_SESSION['menu'][3]['done'] = 0;

        /*
         *
         * Menüreihenfolgen bestimmen
         *
         */ 

        if($menu_order == 1){

            $_SESSION['menu'][1]['file'] = $td;
            $_SESSION['menu'][2]['file'] = $sp;
            $_SESSION['menu'][3]['file'] = $r;

            $_SESSION['menu'][1]['task'] = $task_1;
            $_SESSION['menu'][2]['task'] = $task_2;
            $_SESSION['menu'][3]['task'] = $task_3;


        }elseif($menu_order == 2){

            $_SESSION['menu'][1]['file'] = $td;
            $_SESSION['menu'][2]['file'] = $r;
            $_SESSION['menu'][3]['file'] = $sp;

            $_SESSION['menu'][1]['task'] = $task_2;
            $_SESSION['menu'][2]['task'] = $task_3;
            $_SESSION['menu'][3]['task'] = $task_1;

        }

    }




    // Anhand des aktuellen Fortschritts Menü und Aufgabe herausfinden

    $menu_id = intval($_SESSION['progress']/3) + 1;
    $task_id = $_SESSION['progress'] % 4;

    $cat_wanted  = strtolower($_SESSION['menu'][$menu_id]['task'][$task_id]['category']);
    $cat_current = str_replace('-', '', $_GET['topic']);

    // Wenn aufgabenstellung gelesen und auf start geklickt wurde

    if($_SESSION['initial'] == 1){
        //exit();
        require_once('ask_q.php');
        exit("INITIAL");

    }
    elseif(isset($_POST['start_time'])){

        $_SESSION['menu'][$menu_id]['task'][$task_id]['start_time'] = time();
        $_SESSION['menu'][$menu_id]['task'][$task_id]['clicks']     = 0;
        //exit();
        require_once($_SESSION['menu'][$menu_id]['file']);
        break;
        exit('CASE 2');
    // Wenn gesuchte Kategorie gefunden wurde

    }elseif( $cat_wanted == $cat_current){

        $_SESSION['menu'][$menu_id]['task'][$task_id]['end_time'] = time();
        $_SESSION['menu'][$menu_id]['task'][$task_id]['clicks']++;
        $_SESSION['menu'][$menu_id]['task'][$task_id]['done']     = 1;
        $_SESSION['progress']++;

        require_once('ask_q.php');


        exit('CASE 3');

    // Wenn gesuchte Kategorie noch nicht gefunden wurde Seite anzeigen

    }elseif( $cat_current != $cat_wanted ){
       echo 'Cat Wantet: ' . $cat_wanted . ' != ' . $cat_wanted . ' :Cat Current';
        $_SESSION['menu'][$menu_id]['task'][$task_id]['clicks']++;
        require_once($_SESSION['menu'][$menu_id]['file']);

        exit('CASE 4');
    }else{
        exit('CASE 5');
    }


?>
```

The weird thing is, that at the right point its including the ask_q.php file (Case 3) but also Case 4. I'm wondering because I exited after including by require_once(). And it's even more weird, that the stuff from Case 4 which is included is invisible. I only recognized it in firebug that the content and some included files are changing the optics.

A nother crazy thing is that in Case 4 I give out the conditions in a string and they dont match with the condition :(

AND if i watch at the normal sourcecode it only matches with the file which should be not included but not with the one which is included at all

I know all this sounds realy stupid but I never had a problem like this.  I allready checkt the includet files but its only depending on the main file which is including all other files by conditions.

SO this is stuff from the ask_q.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<?php

$_SESSION['initial'] = 0;
$menu_id = intval($_SESSION['progress']/3) + 1;
$task_id = $_SESSION['progress'] % 4;

?>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Aufgabe <?php echo ($_SESSION['progress'] + 1);?></title>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.no-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
    </head>

    <body id="task">
        <h2>Augabe <?php echo ($_SESSION['progress'] + 1);?></h2>
        <p>Finde den Artikel <strong>"<?php echo $_SESSION['menu'][$menu_id]['task'][$task_id]['article'];?>"</strong> 
        in der Kategorie <strong>"<?php echo $_SESSION['menu'][$menu_id]['task'][$task_id]['category'];?>"</strong></p>

        <form id="start_task" method="post" action="experiment.php">

            <input type="hidden" name="start_time" value="1">

            <input type="submit" value="Los gehts">

        </form>

        <?php echo '<pre style="clear:both;">'; print_r($_SESSION); echo '</pre>';?>

    </body>

</html>
```

And this ist the sourcecode of the other file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
    <head>
        <title>World News</title>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.no-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=UnifrakturCook:700|Rye|UnifrakturMaguntia' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
        <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!--<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>!-->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/topdown.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
    </head>
    <body>

            <div data-role="page">
                <nav id="topdown">
                    <div id="menu-items">
                        <?php require_once('nav-topdown.php');?>
                    </div>
                </nav>


                <header>
                    <?php require_once('header.php');?>
                </header>

                <div id="main-topdown">
                     <div style="height:43px"></div>
                    <?php require_once('content.php');?>
                    <?php //echo 'Cat Wantet = ' . $cat_wanted;?>
                </div>
                <?php echo '<pre style="clear:both;">'; print_r($_SESSION); echo '</pre>';?>
            </div>


            <div data-role="dialog" id="dialogPage">
                <div data-role="header">
                    <h2>Aufgabe</h2>
                </div>
                <div data-role="content">
                    <p>Finde den Artikel <strong>"<?php echo $_SESSION['menu'][$i]['task'][$j]['article'];?>"</strong> 
                    in der Kategorie <strong>"<?php echo $_SESSION['menu'][$i]['task'][$j]['category'];?>"</strong></p>
                    <a id="start" data-theme="b" data-rel="back" data-role="button" href="#" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-transition="pop" data-direction="reverse">
                    Los gehts!
                </a>
                </div>

            </div>

        <script>

            function initResize(){
                $('#topdown').hide();
            }

            $(document).ready(function(){

                initResize();

                var category = "<?php echo $_SESSION['menu'][$i]['task'][$j]['category']; ?>";
                var article  = "<?php echo $_SESSION['menu'][$i]['task'][$j]['article']; ?>";

                //alert('Aufgabe', 'Finde den Artikel <strong>"' + article + '"</strong> in der Kategorie <strong>"' + category + '"</strong>');

                $("#start").click(function(){
                   $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: "ajax.php",
                      data: {task_start: new Date().getTime()},
                      success: function(){
                           $('.ui-dialog').dialog('close');
                      }
                   });

                   return false;
                });

                //console.log($('#main').css('height')); 
                $('#menu-link').click(function(){

                    if( $('#topdown').css('display') != 'block'){

                        $('#topdown').fadeIn();
                    }else{
                        $('#topdown').hide();
                    }
               });


            });

            $(window).resize(function(){
                //initResize();
            });

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

I actually only recognize that theres something wrong because I see the content of the ask_q.php but there is also jquery-mobile included which is obiously not included in the ask_q.php. If I open the sourcecode its just showing me the sourcecode of the other file (not ask_q.php) but when I just watch it in the browser it doesnt show something of that at all.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you are asking. Please edit your question and say exactly what the problem is, what file is being included when it shouldn't and what are the values of the variables used in the conditions

Comment: Wow, including stuff from the session without any obvious signs that the session data is being validated or sanitized?  That's just freaking asking for trouble!  Also, why not just use a class autoloader?

Comment: I want to include the file in case 3. It works so far but it also includes the file from case 4. When i go to sourcecode I see only the source code of the file in case 4 bot not the one from the file in case 3. But the browser rendered also the file from ask_q.

Comment: Can you post the contents of ask_q.php?

Comment: @GordonM this is just running local for an experiment for my bachelorthesis. Anyway what do you mean with validated or sanitized?

Comment: Which condition is it going into? Which case does it `exit` with? There can only be one. PHP is not including anything additionally just because. If there's something extra included, it's because *you wrote code that does so*. Perhaps one of the pages you're including further includes further includes?

Comment: @dopamin90: You asking back probably signals that you have problems looking up terms, so please allow me to offer you a suggested reading: http://foaa.de/blog/2012/11/27/php-validation-and-sanitization/

Comment: http://www.dreamhost.com/dreamscape/2013/05/29/part-2-of-php-security-user-validation-and-sanitization-for-beginners/

Comment: **Clue:** `session_start();` *(is being magically included, right?)*

Comment: @Technoh as i allready told its running just local for an experiment for my bachelorthesis.

Comment: @Fred-ii- what do you mean? session_start() is only in the main file where I include everything.

Comment: @deceze I double checked that. All files are just including what they should. Im wondering because the broser and the sourcecode are showing different things to me

Comment: @dopamin90 It needs to be inside ALL your files being used, and there was no "mention" of it anywhere. It's one of the most important things to mention if it's not shown in your code, when asking a question, and that's always the first one I ask when I don't see it, or have a mention about it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment because my reputation isn't high enough.
Personally, I think that there is something else around all of this that we're not seeing that is causing the problem.

**Obvious questions would be:**

- Where is $cat_wanted and $cat_current being set and changed? - we don't see it
- Where is the rest of the code that sits around the code you've given?
- Is the code you've given an include in itself?
- What are the locations of the files you are including when not ask_q.php? We can't see their names.
- What if one of those files is running and THEN calling ask_q.php?

**Observations**

- You don't need the last elsif. Just make it an ELSE. If $cat_wanted != $cat_current then you don't have to then work out if it's ==
- Instead of having to constantly refer to $_SESSION['menu'][$menu_id]['task'][$task_id] just set $_s =& $_SESSION['menu'][$menu_id]['task'][$task_id]; and use $_s instead.

Answer (score 0):

In order to find a soloution I just kicked out jquery-mobile and everything is working fine. Sourcecodes are looking good and everything is good.

Still got no idea why this is not working. After checking all your answers nothing helped me :(((